# Background video not adjusting on mobile device

Tags: html, css

My issue here is despite everything working on my desktop, when I view it on my phone, the overflow-x: hidden is not working.

Here is the website in question, [ryanjthacker.com](http://ryanjthacker.com/) and here is the [github](https://github.com/thehiddencheese/ryanjthacker.com) files to look at the entire code.

```
<header id="welcome-section">
    <div>
        <p id="hello">Hello, my name is</p>
        <h1 id="ryan">Ryan Thacker</h1>
        <a href="#section-a" class="button">Learn More</a>
    </div>
    <video autoplay muted loop id="bgVideo">
      <source src="images/Beach.webm" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</header>

body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden
}

#welcome-section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

#bgVideo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #bgVideo {
        min-width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use following CSS for `#bgVideo`

```
#bgVideo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  overflow: hidden;}
```

`object-fit` property is important over here. You can learn more about it
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

[image: Applied CSS changes]

Comment: Awesome! I'll test it when I am home, also can I ask how you are viewing the page in iPhone mode and such? That looks like a much better way to test than what I have been doing.

Comment: I think this feature is available on all the modern browsers. You can follow steps from https://superuser.com/questions/1214829/how-can-i-view-the-mobile-version-of-a-webpage-in-google-chrome-for-desktop

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @ryanthacker Since it worked for you, can you accept the answer as well.